# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'engineTypeName'

Tags: eggplant

I'm having this error while trying to run a test in Eggplant Performance.
Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file

> \myWorkspace\projects\myProject\scripts.csv

had a wrong VirtualUser class name and workspace.